# Binding Width of ColumnDefinition doesn't work with GridUnitType.Star

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to change the columnDefinition's width and the rowDefinition's Height during the program, so binding seems a good option to me.
I try to bind the ColumnDefinition's width and the RowDefinition's Height of the Grid to a property that is an Object "StrategyObject".
For the demo, we try to change the column's and row's sizes of the following grid (see Screenshots).

I use the strategy Pattern with the abstract Class "BaseStrategyObject" :

```
public abstract class BaseStrategyObject
{
    protected GridLength gridFirstRowHeight;
    public GridLength GridFirstRowHeight
    {
        get { return this.gridFirstRowHeight; }
    }

    protected GridLength gridSecondRowHeight;
    public GridLength GridSecondRowHeight
    {
        get { return this.gridSecondRowHeight; }
    }

    protected GridLength gridFirstColumnWidth;
    public GridLength GridFirstColumnWidth
    {
        get { return this.gridFirstColumnWidth; }
    }

    protected GridLength gridSecondColumnWidth;
    public GridLength GridSecondColumnWidth
    {
        get { return this.gridSecondColumnWidth; }
    }
}
```

and here are the three concrete startegy classes :

```
public class Strategy1Object : BaseStrategyObject
{
    public Strategy1Object()
    {
        this.gridFirstColumnWidth = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        this.gridFirstRowHeight = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        this.gridSecondColumnWidth = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        this.gridSecondRowHeight = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    }
}

public class Strategy2Object : BaseStrategyObject
{
    public Strategy2Object()
    {
        this.gridFirstColumnWidth = new GridLength(80, GridUnitType.Star);
        this.gridFirstRowHeight = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        this.gridSecondColumnWidth = new GridLength(20, GridUnitType.Star);
        this.gridSecondRowHeight = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    }
}

public class Strategy3Object : BaseStrategyObject
{
    public Strategy3Object()
    {
        this.gridFirstColumnWidth = new GridLength(80.0, GridUnitType.Pixel);
        this.gridFirstRowHeight = new GridLength(200.0, GridUnitType.Pixel);
        this.gridSecondColumnWidth = new GridLength(200.0, GridUnitType.Pixel);
        this.gridSecondRowHeight = new GridLength(80.0, GridUnitType.Pixel);
    }
}
```

The Xaml code of the window :

```
<Window x:Class="GridAsteriskBindingtest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Click="Strategy1_Click">Strategy1</Button>
        <Button Click="Strategy2_Click">Strategy2</Button>
        <Button Click="Strategy3_Click">Strategy3</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=StrategyObject.GridFirstRowHeight}"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=StrategyObject.GridSecondRowHeight}"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=StrategyObject.GridFirstColumnWidth}"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=StrategyObject.GridFirstColumnWidth}"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
            Fill="Red"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
            Fill="Yellow"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
            Fill="Blue"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
            Fill="Green"/>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

and the .cs of the window :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window , INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BaseStrategyObject strategyObject;
    public BaseStrategyObject StrategyObject
    {
        get { return this.strategyObject; }
        set
        {
            this.strategyObject = value;
            OnStrategyObjectChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.strategyObject = new Strategy1Object();

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Strategy1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.StrategyObject = new Strategy1Object();
    }

    private void Strategy2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.StrategyObject = new Strategy2Object();
    }

    private void Strategy3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.StrategyObject = new Strategy3Object();
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnStrategyObjectChanged()
    {
        if(this.PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("StrategyObject"));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Clicking on the buttons apply a new object to the "StrategyObject" property.

When we launch the program, the Strategy3 (with specific sizes GridUnit.Pixel) works fine, but it doesn't work with the two other strategies ( Strategy 1 and 2 (the number of stars is not taken into account :-( )).

Here are the ScreenShots ( Strategy 1 and 2 give the same result).

[Strategy 1 & 2 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMQj5.png)

[Strategy 3 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFkd7.png)

Am I doing something wrong ? Thanks !

Comment: Could you show the results of applying strategies?

Comment: Have you tried to call yourgrid.UpdateLayout() after changing StrategyObject?

Comment: this.StrategyObject = new Strategy2Object();
this.UpdateLayout();

Comment: Unfortunately no, this doesn't make a difference. ( Results have beend added)

Comment: I was thinking in giving a name to your grid (`<Grid x:Name="grid1">`) and then `this.StrategyObject = new Strategy2Object(); this.grid1.UpdateLayout();` Give it a try..

Comment: ok, i just tried, the result is the same :-( . In the project where I met the problem, the strategy object is in reality defined in a viewModel class ( for MVVM, i have not mentioned it here to simplify as much as possible the problem ), i think i should not use names ?

Comment: Another thing to try (i'm running out of ideas :) ).In your Strategy1Object() and Strategy2Object(), before setting heghts and widths to star, try setting them to 0 pixels and then to star. Maybe it needs to first srink to then calculate sizes.

Comment: ok i just tried ( doesn't change the result). In the Strategy2Object Constructor, the value "0 pixel " will directly be overriden by the value with the star, i think that's why the column and row definitions don't see it. the only way to ask the binding to update is by replacing the Strategy object ? Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Ehhmm.. well,i finally created a sample project to test it and well, it works ok to me. Just one thing, in your Grid.ColumnDefinitions, you are binding the same GridFirstColumnWidth. Change the second one to GridSecondColumnWidth and try it

Comment: oh, yes sorry, i'm blind. Thank you